# Should I use waterproofing product or caulk at the base of my foundation walls?

Tags: waterproofing

So I am about to Drylok my basement to treat old cinder blocks with a hint of moisture. I have the old asbestos tiles on the floor.  I know the dangers of removing these.  Basically all of the tiles along the wall have popped up due to moisture.  So I have the bare slab meeting the wall at the base.

Should I Drylok down to the slab and a couple inches over, or is there some kind of masonry caulk to put down where the slab meets the wall?

Comment: Asbestos is nasty in general, but floor tiles are fairly harmless unless you damage them. Simply removing them carefully should not be a big deal. http://www.cpsc.gov/en/Safety-Education/Safety-Guides/Home/Asbestos-In-The-Home/

Answer (score 1):

The waterproofing material's spec sheet will tell you how wide of cracks it's designed to accommodate. That should be your guide. If your joints are wider than that, move to a caulk. If they're extremely wide (over 3/8" or so), consider a rope caulk or a masonry patch product as support for the sealer product.